mysql innodb - copying db manually and register it
I'm creating a test setup such that at the start of each test, I will create an isolated db based on the original DB (40 tables, 14mb size total).
When using mysqldump+mysql or mydumper+myloader, the load of the dump in each strategy takes 600ms. When creating a dump without data, the load takes > 500ms.
I need to make it much much smaller. because when running multiple tests cocnurrently, the parallel import eventually increases to multiple seconds.
When trying to do it manually, I saw that using cp -r /var/lib/mysql/LocalTests_Test_DB/* /var/lib/mysql/copy_db1 takes 30ms. Looks interesting and promising.
How can I register the cloned DB properly manually?

You must do this one table at a time, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-table-import.html

But manually create the tables using sql queries the -- is what takes most of the time. so im not gaining any speed improvements at all.

That is correct.
